# Disable 'TeamViewer has detected a keyboard shortcut' message

Tags: teamviewer

I keep alt tabbing in and out of a TeamViewer session.

Every time I <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> out, I get a dialog box saying

> TeamViewer has detected a keyboard shortcut. To forward shortcuts to the remote computer please activate the menu item "Actions" - "Send key combinations".
>
> Do you want to forward key combinations immediately?

I do not want to forward key combinations. The only options are "Forward" and "Cancel". It happens every single time and it's an always-on-top message box so it gets in the way.

Can I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a check box underneath saying 'do not ask me again'. Try that and if that doesn't work, go to the 'actions' tab at the top and uncheck the 'send key combinations'.

Hopefully that works for you as it did for me on TeamViewer 12.